# Replacing Google Maps with Cloudmade map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-3, cloudmade

I'm trying to implement something like Paul Kulchenko's datamark:

http://notebook.kulchenko.com/maps/datamark

and I was wondering if there was a way to replace the Google Map with a [Cloudmade one](http://cloudmade.com/). I realize now that there's Google's Styled Maps tool, but I'd like to know of a Cloudmade map working with Google Maps API classes.

Thank you, and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps lets you place your own custom tile overlays on top of (or instead of) the default tiles.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html for documentation on this, or http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example for some OSM specific examples.